# How to search a string from a file and replace it to another with Gulp

Tags: javascript, search, replace, gulp, match

I'd like to use Gulp to get a selector from a file **test1.js** and replace it to **test2.js**

**test1.js**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    ...
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

So, I want to get "app-root" from **test1.js**

**test2.js**

```
var selector = "#selector"
function() {}
```

In the **test2.js**, i want replace "#selector" by "app-root".

I know how to replace a string by another string in a file:

```
gulp.src('test2.js', {base: 'src/'})
.pipe(replace(new RegExp(/#selector/, 'g'), (match, p1) => {
    return 'app-root';
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

But i don't know how to pass "app-root" to the stream replace.

How could i do that with Gulp ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do that with **map-stream**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var map = require('map-stream');
var fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src('./test1.js')
        .pipe(map(function(file, callback) {
            var test = file.contents.toString().match(/selector: '(.*)'/i);
            fs.readFile('./test2.js', function read(err, data) {
                if (test) {
                    fs.writeFile('./test2.js', data.toString().replace('#selector', test[1]));
                }
            });
        }));
});
```